# Edit word document such that there is only one blank line between all paragraphs

Tags: c#, visual-studio

i have a word document with several paragraphs and random number of empty lines between each. i need to modify such that there is only one empty line between all paragraphs this i what i came up with but it does not work

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

namespace DataToPDF
{
    public class ParagraphLine
    {
        public static void RemoveLine()
        {
            object path = @"C:\Users\Desktop\Hey.docx";

            Application wordApp = new Application();

            object missing = System.Type.Missing;
            Document doc = wordApp.Documents.Open(ref path, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

            doc.Paragraphs.LineUnitAfter = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This can be done in Word itself (without any coding). Are you interested in such solution?

Comment: unfortunately this code is to be part of a larger one that automates a combination of processes so it has to be coded

Comment: What is this supposed to do?: `ref path, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                ref missing, ref missing, ref missing` It looks ridiculous

Comment: to ignore having to add the various references for the parameters like format, encoding and XMLTransform

Comment: @EpicKip, haven't done much Office programming, eh? :) Kishen, you can now simplify that with `dynamic`. [See COM Interfaces section of this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments)

Comment: @Crowcoder I've done office programming (sadly) but mainly visio where you never have to give a million ref parameters. So it looked pretty darn weird to me